# Moment.js Check a date is today

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

How do I check a date is actually today (the same date) rather than the difference between hours in a day?

I have three timestamps as examples, one is today (22/07/14) and the other two are yesterday (21/07/14)

```
1406019110000 // today
1405951867000 // yesterday
1405951851000 // yesterday
```

I have tried this but all return false:

```
timestamp = moment.tz(timestamp, tz.name());    
var today = moment('DD/MM/YYYY').isAfter(timestamp, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log(today);
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can use `isSame()`, limiting the granularity to a day:

```
var today = moment(1406019110000);
var yesterday = moment(1405951867000);

if (today.isSame(yesterday, 'd')) {
    // They are on the same day
} else {
    // They are not on the same day
}
```

Comment: Ah cool, I didn't know you could specify the granularity of isSame(). This is a little nicer than my solution. Also, you copied my code :p

Comment: What happens if the date has the same day but from a previous month?

Comment: Forget it I answered my own question. Its smart enough to know its different. moment("2013-03-10 2:30").isSame("2013-04-10 2:30", "day") = false

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `startOf` and `isSame` methods together to achieve your goal here.

Running `startOf('day')` on a moment object will set that moment to - you guessed it - the start of the day it occurs on. If you convert each of your timestamps using this method you can easily compare them to one another using `isSame()`.

For example:

```
var today = moment(1406019110000);
var yesterday = moment(1405951867000); 

if (today.startOf('day').isSame(yesterday.startOf('day'))) {
    // They are on the same day
} else {
    // They are not on the same day
}
```

Comment: actually this is dangerous, startOf will mutate the moment objects so if you go to use it after checking if its the same, it'll always give you 12:00.

Comment: Good point @Ben, Vasyl Demins is a better variant of my answer and should be the "correct" answer.

Comment: What if we clone the moment object and set startOf and check? @Ben

Comment: You could but I'm not sure what that's going to buy you and will be a bit less readable. I still think the @vasyls answer is the correct one

Answer (score 16):

You can try this

```
moment().isSame(moment(timestamp), 'day')
```

Answer (score 3):

Moment to check date is today:

```
let dateStr = '2019-12-03 11:23';
/**
 * to check above date string is today use **isSame()**
 */
const status = moment(dateStr).isSame(moment(), 'day');  // O/P : **true**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var today = 1406019110000; // today
var yesterday = 1405951867000; // yesterday

checkToday(today);
checkToday(yesterday);

function checkToday(timestamp)
{
    if (moment(timestamp).format('DD/MM/YYYY') == moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
        alert('true');
    else
        alert("false");
}
```

Here is the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UCUjV/)**