# Comparing if the provided date is today using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using `moment().diff()` to check if the provided date is today or not. I want to highlight today in my calendar using the code below.

```
isToday = moment().diff(moment('30 December, 2016','DDMMMMY'), 'days') === 0;
```

but the problem is it highlights 2 dates today and tomorrow.

Below is the image where moment diff returns 0 for two dates.

[image]

Is there anyway to address this or some other way to check for today.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the highest voted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26571659/402037

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to check whether day is today.

```
var isToday = moment().format("DDMMYYYY") == moment('30 December, 2016','DDMMMMY').format("DDMMYYYY");
```

Since `diff` gives difference in seconds. You need further calculation from seconds to find today.

Comment: yeah this one worked for me thank you